# How to join two tables that are exactly the same column names with third table with unique column names to create new view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am wanting to create a new view based on joining three tables.

table 1 and table 2 have the same column names but the data in them is representative of different time frames. The third table has columns that are unique in both tables.

My query takes all data of table1 and uses a column in table 1 to extract all records from table 2 that have a match.

and then merge this combined dataset with the third table where ever date is greater than '2017-12-01'

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.lookup_column = table2.lookup_column
    LEFT JOIN table3
        ON table3.lookup_column = table1.lookup_column
        AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'
```

When I run this query to create the new view

```
select * into new_table 
FROM table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table1.lookup_column = table2.lookup_column
        LEFT JOIN table3
            ON table3.lookup_column = table1.lookup_column
            AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'
```

I get the error :

`Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'abc' in table 'new_table' is specified more than once.`

How can I avoid this problem between the two tables where the column names are the exactly the same? or how can I specify that I want to combine table 1 and table 2 on column names?

Edit:

```
input

table 1                table2                 table
col1    col2           col1    col2           col3    col4
abc     def            ghi     jkl            mno      pqr


Output:

col1   col2   col3   col4
abc    def    mno    pqr
ghi    jkl    mno    pqr
```

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  It seems like a clear error message.  List out the columns that you explicitly want in the view.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if I pick all columns from say table1, and the query is looking up the same columns in table 2, will the new view still include data from table two ? or do I have to pick all of the columns in table 2 to display data from table 2?

Comment: You simply need to list the fields you want to see, aliasing them uniquely. ie: select table1.field1 as t1f1, table2.fieldN as t2fN, ...

Comment: And think twice, what would you do with such a view. You are selecting into a new table, not creating a view (and what would you do with such a table?).

Comment: @CetinBasoz what other suggestion do you have? I was asked to create a new view or table using that query. I am new to this so open to all suggesionts.

Comment: You didn't give any sample data and expected output. Such a query might not be the thing at all that you want. When you say "same columns" I would expect combining the data in a vertical fashion, rather than a horizontal one as you are doing. Instead of giving the SQL you tried and the error message, if you give sample data and expected output we might come with a better solution. Also I was pointing to, do you really need this as a view or table really. It might be just an SQL that is meant to run on demand.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I added an input/output. Let me know what you think, a vertical join is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the expected output, and the fact that table1 and table2 are structurally identical, you probably want `UNION`:

```
SELECT table1.foo, table1.bar, table3.*
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.lookup_column = table2.lookup_column
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.lookup_column = table3.lookup_column AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'

UNION ALL

SELECT table2.foo, NULL,       table3.*
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.lookup_column = table2.lookup_column
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.lookup_column = table3.lookup_column AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'
```

Comment: Just tried this, forgot to mention table 3 has 8 column max.  I get error `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.` how can I avoid column number mismatch in the union?

Comment: You must match `table3.*` in _both_ parts of union.

Comment: I got the issue table1 has 1 extra column that is not in table 2. Is there anyway I can include this column in the query?

Comment: The columns count must match and the types must be compatible. Having said that, insert as many `, NULL, ` as necessary so that shorter column count matches the larger one. See revised answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set different names for each column in `table1` and `table2` that you want to copy in `new_table`.
For example:

```
select table1.field1 as T1, table2.field1 as T2,
       table1.field2 as T3, table2.field2 as T4
into new_table 
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.lookup_column = table2.lookup_column
    LEFT JOIN table3
        ON table3.lookup_column = table1.lookup_column
        AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

By select * into [something] you are creating a new table.

You could do this to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewName]

AS

SELECT *

FROM table1

LEFT JOIN table2

    ON table1.lookup_column = table2.lookup_column

LEFT JOIN table3

    ON table3.lookup_column = table1.lookup_column

    AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01';
```

Then you could use the view by:

```
Select * from [ViewName];
```

Comment: thank you, but facing same problem as above, need to do a vertical join

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your sample data and output wanted, that doesn't have anything to do with joining 3 tables and left joins.

```
select * 
from table1
cross join table3
union all
select * 
from table2
cross join table3;
```

You can see a [demo here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf3bf3fac5d974039b1866548dc5f034)

However, your sample data is insufficient to point out expected gotcha. A cross join is a dangerous one if you use without knowing what you are doing.